# c++ invalid vector t subscipt

Tags: c++, vector

```
void readGroups(ifstream &filein) {
vector<string> listOfStringTokens;
string tmpLine = "";
string tokens = "";

string courseCode, groupCode, groupName;
int minGroupSize = 0, maxGroupSize = 0;
int counter = 0;
while (filein.good()){

    getline(filein, tmpLine);
    istringstream iss(tmpLine);

    while (!iss.eof()){
        getline(iss, tokens, ';');
        listOfStringTokens.push_back(tokens);
    }
}
tmpLine = "";
tokens = "";
filein.close();

for (unsigned i = 0; i<listOfStringTokens.size(); i++){
    courseCode = listOfStringTokens.at(i);
    groupCode = listOfStringTokens.at(i+1);
    groupName = listOfStringTokens.at(i+2);
    minGroupSize = converter(listOfStringTokens.at(i+3), minGroupSize);
    maxGroupSize = converter(listOfStringTokens.at(i+4), maxGroupSize);

    cout << courseCode << "\t" << groupCode << "\t" << groupName << "\t"
         << minGroupSize << "\t" << maxGroupSize << "\t" << endl;
    i += 4;
}
```

}

```
int converter(string a, int b) {
stringstream convert;
convert << a;
convert >> b;

convert.str("");
convert.clear();

return b;
```

}

Hi everyone!

It is almost the first time for me using vectors and now i get stuck with this. The source of my  problem is the increase of `unsigned i` variable in the `.at()` in the `for loop` as i brought it to light. However i must make it to get an appropriate output. So i need your help guys to make this code run perfect without modifie the structure of output.

Here's the output how it looks like:

```
xxxxxxxxx    xxxxxxx    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    xx    xx
xxxxxxxxx    xxxxxxx    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    xx    xx
xxxxxxxxx    xxxxxxx    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    x     xx
invalid vector<T> subscript
```

Comment: Why do you clear your stringstream in the converter function? It will go out of scope naturally.

Comment: How you check the file is bad. What if getline fails? Then you will pass nonsense to the next step. Use `while (getline(..)) { .. }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You let `i` reach the largest number allowed to access the vector. The problem is you adding even more when calling "at".

Let's say that `listOfStringTokens` contains 12 Element. Imagine the last iteration: `i<listOfStringTokens.size()` is true and `i` is 11:

```
courseCode = listOfStringTokens.at(i);
```

This will work, because you access the index 11.

```
groupCode = listOfStringTokens.at(i+1);
```

This will *not* work, because `i+1` yields an index that is out of bounds.

You also increment `i` in two different places:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i<listOfStringTokens.size(); i++)
```

and here

```
i += 4;
```

This may cause you to lose oversight at a later point in time. Consider doing all incrementations in the first line.

Comment: Well man, thank for your advice. I thought my bounds checking are good enough. I put 
if (i >= (listOfStringTokens.size() - 4)){ break; } 
and it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Please include an example of what you're talking about. It's very unclear what this user should do in response to your answer.